# Отправка данных с <div> вместе с формой

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

Есть у меня форма с полями, одно из них - выпадающий список, в зависимости от выбранного варианта появляется еще одна выпадайка. Есть кнопка выбрать при клике на нее - результаты этих двух выпадаек пишутся в `<div id="#selected-categories">`. Всё это находится в форме и отправляется аяксом. Как собрать данные с формы - сериализация, и т.д. - вроде бы понятно. А вот как к этим данным добавить то что у меня в этом диве лежит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var selectDiv = document.getElementById("#selected-categories").innerText;
// записываете в переменную и делаете с ней что хотите;
console.log(selectDiv);
```

```html
 <div id="#selected-categories">  sduifyhpiufhvpwieufhpi ieufhgp weiufvhp </div>
```

Comment: При отправке аяксом когда делаю сериализацию данных с формы + данные с div - сериализуется неккоректно
`function sendMail(AjaxRezult, idform, path){
  $.ajax({
   url: path,
dataType: "html",
   data: idform+dataDiv.serialize(),
   ....
});`